# Set up a style from a resource in code

Tags: silverlight

Suppose that I have a style that's been defined in a XAML file.
I want to compile that XAML file into my class library as a resource.

Then, I have a control (a custom telerik gridview column) that needs that style.
In code, I would like to load that XAML resource, and instance a Style object from it.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use merged dictionaries, something like this should work as long as the style you need is in the xaml file:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
    Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Themes/Theming.Blue.xaml", UriKind.Relative)).Stream))
{
    xaml = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
ResourceDictionary rd = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(xaml);

App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help -- I'm almost there, but I'm having trouble understanding how the resources are identified.  In my class library, I have the xaml file set up as an embedded resource.  The problem I have is that Application.GetResourceStream always returns null.  I'm probably not using the right identifier, but I cannot figure out what the magic string is.  (I've tried using the resource name as it appears in Reflector, and some variations of that, but no joy)

Comment: Nevermind -- issue was that I needed to use "Resource" and not "Embedded Resource"  Resource string was: "theAssembly;component/Thenamespace/TheXamlfile.xaml"